# Summation in grouping

Tags: sql

I have a SQL question

Here is the code:

```
SELECT  Kredi_Tipi 'Kredi Tipi' ,  Bakiye
FROM Kredi
LEFT JOIN Bakiye 
ON Kredi.Kredi_no=Bakiye.Kredi_no
```

Result:

```
Kredi Tipi  Bakiye
KMH         1321202
TASIT       2642404
KREDI_KARTI 1321402
KMH         1321402
TASIT       1321402
KREDI_KARTI 2642104
KMH         1321202
TASIT       2642204
KREDI_KARTI 1321202
KMH         1321402
TASIT       2642404
KREDI_KARTI 1321202
TASIT       1321302
KREDI_KARTI 2642204
TASIT       1321302
KREDI_KARTI 2642104
KREDI_KARTI 2642104
KREDI_KARTI 2642104
KMH         2642404
KMH         2642404
KMH         2642404
KMH         1321302
```

Now, I want to display a result that shows the sum of KMH, the sum of KREDI_KARTI and the sum of TASIT. How can I do that?

I want the result to be this, where I sum all the KMH values, all the KREDI_KARTI values and all the TASIT values separately:

```
Kredi Tipi  Bakiye
KMH         14533722
TASIT       11891018
KREDI_KARTI 17174426
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: But I want to sum the values, so Group By doesn't work. Or else I may not know the spesific usage of it

Comment: `Sum(Bakiye) as Bakiye`

Comment: Well, that worked actually. Thanks! @WEI_DBA

Comment: Simple `SUM()` and `GROUP BY()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Aggreation learning please review [GROUP BY + SUM](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php)
Considering Kredi_Tipi , Kredi_no constructs unique key.

```
SELECT  Kredi_Tipi 'Kredi Tipi' ,  SUM(COALESCE(Bakiye,0)) Bakiye
FROM Kredi
LEFT JOIN Bakiye ON Kredi.Kredi_no=Bakiye.Kredi_no
GROUP BY Kredi_Tipi , Kredi_no
```

For Oracle

```
SELECT  Kredi_Tipi 'Kredi Tipi' ,  SUM(NVL(Bakiye,0)) Bakiye
FROM Kredi
LEFT JOIN Bakiye ON Kredi.Kredi_no=Bakiye.Kredi_no
GROUP BY Kredi_Tipi , Kredi_no
```

For MS SQL Server

```
SELECT  Kredi_Tipi 'Kredi Tipi' ,  SUM(IsNull(Bakiye,0)) Bakiye
FROM Kredi
LEFT JOIN Bakiye ON Kredi.Kredi_no=Bakiye.Kredi_no
GROUP BY Kredi_Tipi , Kredi_no
```

Comment: Both Oracle and SQL Server support Standard SQL `COALESCE`, too